# Clickin on Element with Underscore

Tags: c#, web, automation, watin

I'm trying to fill out a form and couple of its inputs have underscores in the *`name`* and *`id`*. I was wondering if that somehow causes the problem.

```
<fieldset>
<label for="user_name">Username</label>
<div class="goodorbad">
<span id="user_name-loading" class="free-or-taken fot-loading">
<img width="24" alt="Checking…" src="/i/loading/fresh-64.gif">
Checking...
</span>
<span id="user_name-free" class="free-or-taken" title="Available">✓</span>
<span id="user_name-taken" class="free-or-taken" title="Taken">×</span>
</div>
<input id="user_name" type="text" autocomplete="off" tabindex="10" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" maxlength="50" value="" name="user_name">
<div class="suggestions">
</fieldset>
```

For some reason I cant find this `Element` by *`Id` or `Name` (Exception thrown ElementNotFound)*.

This is what I've tried so far *(none of the code below worked)*:

```
browser.ElementOfType<TextFieldExtended>(Find.ByClass(new Regex("user.name"))).TypeText("gfgh");

browser.TextField(Find.ById(new Regex("user.name"))).TypeText("gfgh");

browser.TextField(Find.ById("user%5Fname")).TypeText("gfgh");

browser.ElementOfType<TextFieldExtended>("user_name").TypeText("gfgh");

browser.ElementOfType<TextFieldExtended>("user_name").Value="FFF";

browser.Table(Find.ByClass("form-table")).TextField(Find.ByClass("user_name")).TypeText("gfgh");

browser.TextField(Find.ById("user_name")).TypeText("gfgh");
```

Comment: What's the type of `browser`?

Comment: Im using Windows.Forms.WebBrowser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a similar case to mine, here is how to solve it.

Instead of using TextField

```
 browser.TextField(Find.ById("someID")).TypeText("someText");
```

Use Element

```
 browser.Element(Find.ById("someID")).SetAttributeValue("value","someText");
```

Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Searching on IDs and names with underscores works just fine; I do it all the time.  The likely cause is you don't have the correct ID or name (<- this is the most likely), the textbox is in a frame (less likely), or you're not running the WatiN code against the correct running browser; this would also include popups and dialogs. (less likely).

**Sample HTML** - slight change of the id for clarity

```
<html>
<body>
<input name="user_name" id="user_id" value="" maxlength="50" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" tabindex="10" autocomplete="off" type="text">
</body>
</html>
```

**Sample C# / WatiN**

```
IE myIE = new IE();
myIE.GoTo("theCorrectURL");
myIE.TextField("user_id").TypeText("Found By ID");
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);  //not needed other than to watch what is happening
myIE.TextField(Find.ByName("user_name")).TypeText("Found By Name");
```

The above is working and tested on WatiN 2.1, IE9, Win7-64

***Other notes***

1)  Find.ByClass("user_name") isn't going to find it because there is no CSS class defined on your tag.  If you had  then you *could* search like Find.ByClass("theCssClass").

2)  the type of browser is going to be WatiN.Core.IE (or maybe .Firefox)  If it is indeed Windows.Forms.WebBrowser I'd be very suprprised.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've just updated HTML in my question. Please see above. No Iframe present. I've tripple checked my selectors. ByName, ById none of them work. theres another field on the page pass1. I have no problem accessing this elelment. But not the username or email field.

Comment: You are right, underscore works in some cases. Found another site when inputfield Is not found!